# How do you use JavaScript to get the current city the user is in and display it in a <h2>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, weather, city

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getLocation").on("click", function(){
        $.getJSON('https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=?') 
        .done (function(location) {
            $('#city').html(location.city);             
        });
    });
});
```

This is the current JavaScript I've been using, and [here](https://codepen.io/apeck14/pen/rydgRM/?editors=1010) is the link to the CodePen I'm using it for. I'm using the location of the users city to find the weather of that city as well.

I've read on multiple sites about how to use several different API's to get the users city location, but non have worked in my project. Thanks for the help, in advance.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on my previous answer, a cleaner and more vanilla JavaScript way to get the coordinates is like so.

This is just a few short lines longer and the benefits are massive:

1. Don't have to include jQuery library, which is massive and slows down page load times
2. **This means you won't have to rely on a HEAVY EXTERNAL API to make AJAX calls for the same data (and other useless API-specific info e.g. requestID) and will seriously streamline your application**.
3. Avoids the use of many callbacks and thus avoids callback hell.

See image below for results. Super lightweight and fast. For more detailed information, have a look at [MDN - Using Geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    // Do something with coordinates returned
    function processCoords(position) {
        let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        let first_div = document.querySelector('div');
        let el_h2 = document.createElement('h2');

        // Set h2 text as coordinates
        el_h2.innerText = `Latitude: ${latitude}, Longitude: ${longitude}`;

        // Append h2 to document
        first_div.appendChild(el_h2);
    }

    // Fetch Coordinates
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(processCoords);
}
```

**To get the City:**

> It's usually best practice to store the coordinates only in your db
>   and then make separate city requests when required. This makes things
>   easier when you want to implement say a Map View on Mobile or Desktop,
>   which all use coordinates rather than names for plots.

You can use the Google Maps API and passing in the LatLong data directly. Someone has created a gist on how to do it [here](https://gist.github.com/AmirHossein/92a0597b5f723b19c648).

Benefit of using GMaps instead of Geo-IP:

1. Google Maps API is heavily, heavily, heavily optimised. From faster
   servers to better-written code. You can also import a specific part
   of the GMaps API so you can cut down on your source code size. All
   of this adds up to a much faster experience.
2. GMaps can be assumed to be around for longer than a 3rd party site like Geo-Ip.

[image]

Comment: I'll try this way as well! Thanks dude.

Comment: Np. Good luck with your projects!

Comment: The issue is I don't want to only display the coordinates, but the actual city of the coordinates. Suggestions?

Comment: If you found it helpful could you please mark it as the answer and upvote? Would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this working

```
 function ipLookUp () {
$.ajax('http://ip-api.com/json')
    .then(
        function success(response) {
           console.log(response.city); //Users City
          console.log(response.country); //Users Country
        },
       function fail(data, status) {
            console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of',
                status);
        }
    );}ipLookUp()
```

Comment: You should state: As HTTPS is a quasi-standard on most websites these days, this does not help as it only runs on HTTP. The HTTPS interface requires a paid membership. And calling a HTTP resource from within a HTTPS site throws a "Mixed Content" error on most browsers. An alternative service would be https://geolocation-db.com